# How to explain the strange behaviour about Function Nothing

Tags: list-manipulation

There are some things wrong when i try to delete an element of a list by using function `Nothing`.
Here is a simple  example:

```
{a = Range[10], a[[1]], a[[1]] = Nothing, a}(*{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},1,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}*)
```

It works,but when i try it again.

```
{a[[1]], a[[1]] = Nothing, a}(*{2,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}*)
```

It doesn't work.Finally i found that the first element of **a** could be deleted if i evaluate the code `a[[2]]=Nothing`,Any answer will be most appreciated

Comment: Please do not use the [Bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag for new questions - see the tags description for why

Comment: Thank you for the hint!@Lukas Lang

Comment: Note: while this one is about `Nothing` rather than `Sequence`, the two are very similar, and the mechanism that is what puzzles the OP, is exactly the same. In this sense, this is still a duplicate, thus voting to close (apparently, I even mentioned `Nothing` in my answer there).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Your answer is woefully ncomplete. A proper discussion of `Nothing` will [never omit this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HqyEHqEYho)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You are totally right. In fact, that link of yours ***is*** the answer, should be posted / accepted instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Part` assignment performs in-place modification of an expression without evaluation of the result. At the same time, on the Documentation page for `Nothing` we read:

> `Nothing` is removed as part of the standard evaluation process.

So after evaluation of `a[[1]] = Nothing` you still have a `List` of length `10` with first element being `Nothing`. You can replace `Nothing` with anything else in the same way again:

```
a[[1]] = Nothing;
Definition[a]
a[[1]] = Missing[];
Definition[a]
```

> ```
> a={Nothing,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
>
> a={Missing[],2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
> ```

You can remove `Nothing` by evaluating the expression:

```
a[[1]] = Nothing;
Definition[a]
a = a;
Definition[a]
```

> ```
> a={Nothing,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
> a={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
> ```

---

Instead of `Nothing` you can use such functions as `Delete`, `Drop`, `Take` or `ReplacePart` for the same purpose.

Answer (score 12):

Taking a look at `?a` shows what's going on:

```
?a

(* Global`a *)

(* a={Nothing,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} *)
```

It seems that  `Part` (`[[...]]`) does not apply the effect of `Nothing` after the replacement has been done, leaving you with a list that is still 10 elements long. So the second `a[[1]]=...` simply replaces the `Nothing` in the first element with `Nothing` again.

You case use [`Delete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) to do the deletion properly:

```
{a = Range[10], a[[1]], a = Delete[a, 1], a}
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 1, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
  10}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)

{a[[1]], a = Delete[a, 1], a}
(* {2, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!i get it.

Comment: Interesting that `{a, b, Nothing, c, d, Nothing}; (* new line *)
% // Length` gives 4.

Comment: @Markhaim That happens because the list gets evaluated and after evaluation the `Nothings` will have disappeared. If you compare `Length[Unevaluated[{1, Nothing, 3}]]` with `Length[{1, Nothing, 3}]`, you'll see the same effect.